# WCF rest service multiple images upload

Tags: wcf

How can i upload multiple images in WCF rest service.Someone help me to fixed out this issue.
Images receive as Byte array from android device.`
and the requirement is to do a single call from andriod to wcf rest service

Below is my code

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadFilePost?FileName={FileName}&WallPostId={WallPostId}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public MobileFileUploadResponse UploadFilePost(List<Stream> Image, string FileName, long WallPostId)
    {
         ServicesMapper serviceMapper = new ServicesMapper();
         return serviceMapper.UploadFilePost(Image, FileName, WallPostId);
```

}

Comment: Did you find any solution?